# When adding navbar-toggler my navbar-right link to the About page disappears. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, navbar

I have had these issues with my navbar and can't find what am I doing wrong. In the beginning, I just took out the code for the toggle and the link for the About page would be where it should; on the right-hand side of my navbar. Now I got to the point where I need the hamburger nav menu, so I have to add the toggle code, but then the link to my About page disappears completely and there is no toggle either. The second issue is the appearance of the little bar on the left side of my logo.

**Screenshot of the page:**

[image: Screenshot of the page]

**My code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Saasapp</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
    family=Open+Sans:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data- 
    turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 
    'reload' %>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class='container'>
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           </button>
        <%= link_to root_path, class: "navbar-brand" do %>
          <i class="fas fa-users"></i> DevMatch
          <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <%= link_to "About", about_path, id: 
                    "navbar-right" %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <%= yield %>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <%= link_to "About", about_path, id: "navbar-right" %>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

The navbar-right class should be added to the ul instead of the div.

The toggle will show up if you make you screen smaller.